# Getting null values in student.java method "student1()" from studentDAO.java?

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc

student.java

```
import java.io.*;

public class Student implements Serializable  {

    String name;
    String id1,phone,clas;

    public Student() {    
    }

    public String showStudent() {
        return  "Name: "+name+" Address: "+clas+" Phone: "+phone+" ID: "+id1;
    }

    public void Student1(String  id,String n,String c,String ph) {
        name=n;
        id1=id;
        phone=ph;
        clas=c;
    }
}
```

StudentDAO.java

```
import java.sql.*; 
import java.io.*;

public class StudentDAO implements Serializable {

    static  String id,detailsi,nam,ph,clas,i;

    public void searchinfo(String id2) {
        id=id2;
        try {
            String url="jdbc:ucanaccess://C:\\Users\\Asim Iqbal\\Documents\\IT.accdb";
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            String sql= "SELECT * FROM Student WHERE ID=?";
            PreparedStatement  stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            stmt.setString(1,id);
            ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery();
            if (rs.next()) {
                i=rs.getString("ID");
                nam=rs.getString("Name"); 
                clas=rs.getString("Class");
                ph=rs.getString("Phone");
                Student studentinfo=new Student();
                studentinfo.Student1(i, nam, clas, ph);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
        }
    } 
}
```

second.jsp

```
<html> 
    <body>
        <% 
            String id =request.getParameter("ID1");
            StudentDAO std=new StudentDAO();
            Student st=new Student();
            std.searchinfo("id");
        %>
        <h1> <%=st.showStudent()%> </h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Getting null values in student.java  method   "student1()"  from studentDAO.java??  StudentDAO.java connects DB properly and give result properly as individually.. But not passing values as a parameter to "student1()" in Student.java file..
Please suggest where i am getting wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `public void searchinfo(String id2)` to `public Student searchinfo(String id2)` and return studentinfo[i.e. Student object].

//JSP corrections

```
String id = request.getParameter("ID1");
StudentDAO std = new StudentDAO();

Student st = std.searchinfo(id);
```

Comment: I edit the code but still getting null values in the browser.. Rajesh

Answer (score 1):

Issue is because of your creating two instance of student, one in StudentDAO and other second.jsp.
Instance created in StudentDAO  will contains values.But you are not using that object,Your creating new object in second.jsp value and that object does not contains any values. So your getting null values.

Fix:
**StudentDAO**

```
public Student searchinfo(String id2) {
```

.
.
.
.

```
   Student studentinfo=new Student();
   studentinfo.Student1(i, nam, clas, ph);
return studentinfo;
```

}

**second.jsp**

```
StudentDAO std=new StudentDAO();
Student st= std.searchinfo("id");
<h1> <%=st.showStudent()%> </h1>
```

Comment: Thandaraj, how to use that object refrence in my jsp page which contain values in StudentDAO?

Comment: Hi Faisal. Your searchinfo method of StudentDAO returns Student  object(contains student object).  you can see I have  changed the method signature of searchinfo "public Student searchinfo(String id2)". Try it and let me know if you face any other issue