# Getting null values in the browser from jsp page?

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc

JSP page

```
<%@ page import="Student.*"%>

<html>


<body>


      <%


   String id =request.getParameter("ID1");

     StudentDAO std=new StudentDAO();
    Student st=std.searchinfo("id");


   %>

        <h1> <%=st.showStudent()%> </h1>


 </body>

</html>
```

Student.java

```
import java.io.*;

public class Student implements Serializable  {

String name;

    String id1,phone,clas;

   public Student()
    {

    }

    public String showStudent()

    {

       return  "Name: "+name+" Address: "+clas+" Phone: "+phone+" ID: "+id1;
    }
   public void Student1(String  id,String n,String c,String ph)

    {

         name=n;
         id1=id;
         phone=ph;
        clas=c;
    }

}
```

StudentDAO.java

```
import java.sql.*; 

    import java.io.*;

     public class StudentDAO implements Serializable
    {

          static  String i,id,nam,clas,ph;

         Student studentinfo=new Student();

        public Student searchinfo(String id2)
        {
            id=id2;


        try{

        String url="jdbc:ucanaccess://C:\\Users\\Asim Iqbal\\Documents\\IT.accdb";

       Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);

        String sql= "SELECT * FROM Student WHERE ID=?";

                  PreparedStatement  stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                    stmt.setString(1,id);
                   ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery();
                    if (rs.next())
                    {
                        i=rs.getString("ID");

                      nam=rs.getString("Name"); 


                       clas=rs.getString("Class");
                        ph=rs.getString("Phone");
                       studentinfo.Student1(i, nam, clas, ph);
                    }
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                }
            return studentinfo;
       } 
    }
```

This is the error.. But StudentDAO.java connect DB properly and give output as individually.. But in the browser it give null values as follows..

Name: null Address: null Phone: null ID: null

Comment: The fact that you get null fields means that the Student object itself is not null. What are the column names and types in your database table? Do that match the rs.getString() calls?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting null values in student.java method "student1()" from studentDAO.java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31137722/getting-null-values-in-student-java-method-student1-from-studentdao-java)

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body>
      <%
   String id =request.getParameter("ID1");
     StudentDAO std=new StudentDAO();
```

> Student st=std.searchinfo(id);

```
   %>
        <h1> <%=st.showStudent()%> </h1>
 </body>
</html>
```

Change you jsp page code as above, you should pass the id value as an argument to a DAO method, What your passing now is a string "id".

> Remember writing a java code inside a jsp is a bad practise